# Kubernetes : node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set up a local storage as outlined here (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/) . I'm getting the following error that the scheduler is unable to schedule the pods . The local storage is mapped to one of the worker node. I tried setting up the local storage on master node and I got the same error. WHere am I going wrong?

Warning  FailedScheduling  24s (x2 over 24s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector, 2 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------

kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
rpi-k8-workernode-2   Ready    <none>   92d   v1.15.0   192.168.100.50   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)   4.19.42-v7+         docker://18.9.0
rpi-mon-k8-worker     Ready    <none>   91d   v1.15.0   192.168.100.22   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)   4.19.42-v7+         docker://18.9.0
udubuntu              Ready    master   92d   v1.15.1   192.168.100.24   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS               4.15.0-55-generic   docker://19.3.4

-------------------------------------------------------------------
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
------------------------------------------------------------------------

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-ghost
  namespace: ghost
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/mydrive/ghost-data/
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - rpi-mon-k8-worker
------------------------------------------------------------------------
apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:
  name: pvc-ghost
  namespace: ghost
  labels:
    pv: pv-ghost

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce

  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: pv-ghost
------------------------------------------------------------------------

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:
    deployment-ghost
  namespace: ghost
  labels:
    env: prod
    app: ghost-app

spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ghost-app-pod
      labels:
        app:  ghost-app
        env:  production
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ghost
          image: arm32v7/ghost
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /var/lib/ghost/content
             name: ghost-blog-data
          securityContext:
            privileged: True
 volumes:
      - name: ghost-blog-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-ghost
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: arm

  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ghost-app


kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   LABELS
rpi-k8-workernode-2   Ready    <none>   93d   v1.15.0   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm,kubernetes.io/hostname=rpi-k8-workernode-2,kubernetes.io/os=linux
rpi-mon-k8-worker     Ready    <none>   93d   v1.15.0   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm,kubernetes.io/hostname=rpi-mon-k8-worker,kubernetes.io/os=linux
udubuntu              Ready    master   93d   v1.15.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=udubuntu,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=

-----------------------------------------------------------
ud@udubuntu:~/kube-files$ kubectl describe pvc pvc-ghost -n ghost
Name:          pvc-ghost
Namespace:     ghost
StorageClass:  manual
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        pv=pv-ghost
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"pv":"pv-ghost"},"name":"pvc-ghost","namespace":"...
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age               From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----              ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  6s (x2 over 21s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the warning `1 node(s) didn't match node selector, 2 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.`, you set a `nodeSelector` in the deployment-ghost, so one of your worker nodes didn't match with this selector.If you delete the `nodeSelector` field from that .yaml file. In this way the pod will be deployed to a node where the `PV` is created. AFAIK, it isn't possible to deploy a pod to a worker which the `PV` used to claim is in the another worker node. 
And finally, in the other nodes, no `PV`s created. You can check the created `PV`s and `PVC`s by:

```
kubectl get pv
kubectl get pvc -n <namespace>
```

and the check the details of them by:

```
kubectl describe pv <pv_name> 
kubectl describe pv <pv_name> -n <namespace>
```

You issue is explained in the official documentation in [her](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) which says :

> Claims can specify a label selector to further filter the set of
>   volumes. Only the volumes whose labels match the selector can be bound
>   to the claim. The selector can consist of two fields:
>
> 1- matchLabels - the volume must have a label with this value
>
> 2- matchExpressions - a list of requirements made by specifying key, list of values, and operator that relates the key and values. Valid operators include In, NotIn, Exists, and DoesNotExist

So, edit the PersistentVolume file and add the labels field to be look like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-ghost
  labels:
    name: pv-ghost
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/mydrive/ghost-data/
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - rpi-mon-k8-worker
```

It isn't necessary to add the **namespace** field to `kind: persistantVolume` because `PersistentVolumes` binds are exclusive, and `PersistentVolumeClaims` are namespaced objects.

I test it and it works for me.

Comment: @majid..thanks for your inputs. I cannot delete the node selector on the deployment yaml since the worker nodes are arm nodes whereas the master node is an intel node. To ensure that only arm images are deployed ..I have used the node selector.

Comment: @IT_novice OK! then you must match the node name which specify in persistent  volume yaml file (`values: - rpi-mon-k8-worker`) with the node label which related to the selected node.

Comment: sorry I am not able to follow what you are saying. Are you are suggesting that I change the nodeselector on the deployment yaml file to match the node name ? I tried that as well but I get the same error

Comment: Please send the output of `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` on your master

Comment: I have updated the question with the output that shows the labels

Comment: First change the nodeSelector value to `kubernetes.io/hostname=rpi-mon-k8-worker` and then check the pvc has been created properly by `kubectl get pvc`

Comment: That's a really good one, my PVC wasn't having the same namespace as my Pod, which leads to failure in mounting to my volume.